# mongod 4.4 CPU hogs/stalls leading to client queries timedout

Tags: mongodb

``Hi Team,

Since migrating to MongoDB 4.4, we have been encountering a recurring issue of client queries timing out frequently. Upon monitoring the CPU usage during these occurrences, we have noticed that mongod's CPU usage is unusually high, despite there not being a significant increase in operations.

This erratic CPU usage has been observed intermittently, and our application has a monitoring thread that checks the replicStatus and reports NO_PRIMARY during such times.

Mongo- Server Version: 4.4.18

Mongo Client Java Driver version: 3.12.9

Standalone or Replica : 4 data bearing + 1 arbiter

Server Option:

root       52039  161  2.5 12649240 7229872 ?    S<Ll Apr06 4415:45 /usr/bin/mongod --ipv6 --slowms 500 --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 22 --enableMajorityReadConcern false --bind_ip_all --keyFile /root/.dbkey --port 27717 --dbpath=/var/data/sessions.1/h --replSet set01h --fork --pidfilepath /var/run/sessionmgr-27717.pid --oplogSize 5120 --logpath /var/log/mongodb-27717.log --logappend --quiet

Storage Engine : WT

Application Monitors the replicaStatus periodically reporting, TYPE=UNKNOWN for PRIMARY intermittently.

2023-04-07 23:02:30,944 [pool-2-thread-1] replicaset status: ReplicaSetStatus{name=set01h, cluster=ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion

{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=795436, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='null', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:30 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414267859844}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}
, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1152849, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:30 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414649210810}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion

{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=943462, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:30 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414619113856}]}}

Immediately in the next sec, the replicaSet detects PRIMARY

2023-04-07 23:02:31,260 [pool-2-thread-1] replicaset status: ReplicaSetStatus{name=set01h, cluster=ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}
, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=772997, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='null', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414767866623}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=16803136, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000080, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414870305431}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion

{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1152849, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:30 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414649210810}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}
, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=943462, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:30 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116414619113856}]}}

But again moves to UKNOWN and later to a proper state

2023-04-07 23:02:31,544 [pool-2-thread-1] replicaset status: ReplicaSetStatus{name=set01h, cluster=ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion

{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=729934, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='null', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415267757469}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}
, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1059673, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415149889939}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion

{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=941532, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415120136591}]}}

2023-04-07 23:02:31,764 [pool-3-thread-1] replicaset status: ReplicaSetStatus{name=set01h, cluster=ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}
, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=729934, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='null', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415267757469}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=13549634, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000080, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415370985974}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion

{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1059673, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415149889939}, ServerDescription{address=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 18]}
, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=941532, setName='set01h', canonicalAddress=nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717, hosts=[nd2bwa3psm16va:27717, nd2bwa3psm15va:27717, nd2bwa3psm16vb:27717, nd2bwa3psm15vb:27717], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='nd2bwa3psm15va:27717', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=27149688, lastWriteDate=Fri Apr 07 23:02:31 UTC 2023, lastUpdateTimeNanos=116415120136591}]}}

top - 23:02:27 up 1 day,  7:17,  0 users,  load average: 21.07, 23.62, 26.89
Tasks: 303 total,   1 running, 301 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 56.5 us, 15.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 22.7 id,  0.0 wa,  2.1 hi,  3.5 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 273809.9 total, 204977.1 free,  30793.4 used,  38039.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used. 205453.0 avail Mem

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
```

52039 root       5 -15   12.0g   7.2g  36920 S 237.7   2.7   2977:27 mongod

–
top - 23:02:30 up 1 day,  7:17,  0 users,  load average: 21.07, 23.62, 26.89
Tasks: 301 total,   2 running, 299 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 87.8 us,  4.8 sy,  0.0 ni,  5.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.9 hi,  1.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 273809.9 total, 204977.1 free,  30793.4 used,  38039.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used. 205453.0 avail Mem

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
```

52039 root       5 -15   12.1g   7.3g  36920 S 999.9   2.7   2977:48 mongod

–

PID : 52039 mongostats
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn    set repl                time
65  1449    969     68     701   821|0  1.9% 30.2%       0 12.0G 7.19G 0|1 1|1  5.79m   14.8m  741 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:21.449
71  1572   1063     76     870   959|0  1.7% 30.2%       0 12.0G 7.20G 0|0 2|0  6.45m   16.2m  744 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:22.426
69  1581   1064     74     841   988|0  1.8% 30.2%       0 12.0G 7.20G 0|0 1|0  6.53m   16.2m  744 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:23.423
88  1602   1090     77     793   870|0  1.8% 30.3%       0 12.0G 7.20G 0|0 1|1  6.55m   16.5m  741 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:24.431
67  1507   1026     78     954  1013|0  1.9% 30.1%       0 12.0G 7.20G 0|0 1|1  6.44m   15.8m  741 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:25.427
59  1601   1122     86     778   817|0  1.9% 30.1%       0 12.0G 7.19G 0|1 1|0  6.48m   16.6m  741 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:26.419
81  1609   1068     73     779   908|0  2.0% 30.2%       0 12.0G 7.19G 0|1 1|0  6.46m   16.3m  741 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:27.435
15   417    189     32     225   364|0  1.9% 30.1%       0 11.9G 7.31G 0|0 2|8  1.44m   2.93m  612 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:30.352
*0   184     *0      9      18  2643|0  1.9% 30.2%       0 11.8G 7.32G 0|0 1|1   318k   2.89m  413 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:30.564
140  1499    809     94     364  6105|0  2.0% 30.2%       0 11.6G 7.31G 0|0 1|5  5.90m   17.7m  292 set01h  PRI Apr  7 23:02:31.422
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn    set repl

Comment: Hi Experts, could you please help on this

Comment: Do you have ntp configured in your servers? Also looks like dns resolution issue  or very higly loaded servers? what is your current work load?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since the PRIMARY seems unavailable, infact NO primaries are seen for 1-2 sec, the application(client) queries are getting timedout resulting in bad customer experience.

We tried to reduce the load(query) to the mongo but it looks the same. We use /etc/hosts for name resolution and do not use DNS at all. 

We need to know why time to time, mongod hogs.  Kindly help

Comment: How your queries looks like , are they indexed?

Answer (score 0):

1. According to the compatibility matrix your client java driver version 3.12.9 is not compatible with mongod version 4.4 see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/) (The Driver version will work with the MongoDB version, but not all new MongoDB features are supported) , you will need to upgrade to at least java driver version 4.1.

2. What do you see when you execute "top -H PID(mongod)"  when your mongod is using heavily your CPU?
3. Provide some more details about your database schema , size and executed update,delete,find queries?